# How to use gamRR calculate relative risk in R

Tags: r, gam

I use gam function from mgcv package, and want to calculate relative risks. I want to use gamRR function from gamRR package. The warning is as follows:

`` >single5=gam(count~`PM2.5_lag5`+ns(temp,7)+ns(humidity,7)+ns(DATE,6)+DOW,data=dailypollutant,family=poisson(link="log")) ``

`` >gamRR(single5,ref=c(`PM2.5_lag5`=dailypollutant$PM2.5_lag5[5],temp=dailypollutant$temp[5],humidity=dailypollutant$humidity[5],DATA=dailypollutant$DATE[5],DOW=dailypollutant$DOW[5]),est=`PM2.5_lag5`,data=dailypollutant) ``

```
Error in gamRR(single5, ref = c(PM2.5_lag5 = dailypollutant$PM2.5_lag5[5],  : 
  Some variables in the 'ref' argument are not in the model!
```

However, the variables used in gamRR are the same as the gam function. Could anyone tell me how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: SORRY, the second code is ```>gamRR(single5,ref=c(`PM2.5_lag5`=dailypollutant$PM2.5_lag5[5],temp=dailypollutant$temp[5],humidity=dailypollutant$humidity[5],DATE=dailypollutant$DATE[5],DOW=dailypollutant$DOW[5]),est=`PM2.5_lag5`,data=dailypollutant)```

Comment: Why are you using `ns()`? Those won't be penalized splines, which is the main reason to use `gam()` over say `lm()` or `glm()` with `ns()` terms.